# Can I make files deleted on the NAS automatically go to the recycle bin?

Tags: network-shares, nas, network-drive

So when I use my desktop and delete \NAS\Files\Directory, that I can still recover the files from the NAS' recycle bin.

The NAS is just a normal Windows share on a Windows 7 computer. I don't like the idea that removing a file is permanent.

Currently when I delete a file on the Windows share over the network, it will not be moved to the recycle bin, but removed permanently. This seems normal behavior.

Comment: `When I delete a file on the NAS, it will be removed permanently. … recover the files from the NAS' recycle bin` There is no Recycle Bin on the NAS. Each storage volume has a [“type”](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364939.aspx) and Windows only supports Recycle Bins on fixed (read internal) drives. It does not use Recycle Bins on removable drives (floppies, thumb-drives, memory-cards, external HDDs), optical drives, RAM drives, or network drives (including NAS shares). But I have seen programs that make their own third-party counterpart, like the Norton Recovery Bin.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there is no built-in solution, since when you delete files in windows, they are moved into the drives recycle bin folder. I think its understandable that windows does not copy files you delete on the network over to your machine, to store them in a recycler.

There is, however, a workaround to achieve recycle bin coverage for network drives (should work from Vista upwards):

1. Map a network drive to the network share you want to use. Make sure that the drive is re-connected on logon.
2. Browse to C:\users\ `<user name>`.
3. Right-click on one of the folders in this location (I chose saved games) and click properties.
4. Select the Location tab.
5. Click Move, browse to the root of the drive you mapped in step 1, and click Select Folder.
6. Click Ok and click yes in the dialogue box that appears.
7. Repeat these same steps for all users on the computer.

You can now verify that the network drive is protected by the recycle bin by right-clicking on the recycle bin and clicking properties. **The network drive should be listed in the Recycle Bin Locations column.**

Some warnings:

1. This only protects files accessed through the mapped network drive, and not by UNC paths. So for example, if you mapped `\\server\share` to z:, and delete something off the z drive, it will go to the recycle bin. However, if you browse to `\\server\share` and delete a file, it will be deleted directly.
2. I don't know what will happen if your network drive is not available, so beware. This may not work well with laptops.
3. What ever files that were supposed to be stored in the folder you select in step 3 will now be stored on your mapped network drive by default. This can actually be quite useful.

Comment: Are you sure that works? Have you tested it? Where does Windows put the recycled files?

Comment: Yes I am. Yes I did. I do not know however, where the Files are put, but they are shown in your recycler when you delete them, and you can restore them from there.

Comment: Argh! You don’t know? What kind of answer is that‽ I can’t let just something like that go; now I *have* to try it to find out. :^Þ